# CGI-Script на C. Вывод Apache http 500 server error

Tags: c, apache, cgi

Друзья добрый день.На свой локальный компютер (`linux Ubuntu 18.04`) загрузил  сервер `Apache 2.1`.Сервер работает без проблем (`syntax ok` ). Возникла такая проблема  .Для тестирования  создал скрипт  на  языке `C`. Скрипт добавил в папку  `/usr/lib/cgi-bin/` как написано в настройках сервера. Но при вводе   `localhost/cgi-bin/script.cgi`   выводится  `http 500 server error` . Можете подсказать  вчем проблема .Скажу что  скрип скомпилировал на `GNU` компиляторе.Заранее спасибо

Вот `CGI-script` на `C`

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void) {
int num;
time_t t;
srand (time ( &t) ) ;

num = rand() % 10;

printf ("Content-type: text/html \n");
printf("Pragma: no-cache\n");
printf ( "\n");
printf("<!DOCTYPE  html>");
printf("<html lang='en'>");
printf("<head>");
printf("<title>Look This Amazing</title>");
printf("<meta charset='utf-8'>");
printf("</head>");
printf("<body>");
printf("<h1>Look This Amazing!</h1>");
printf("</body>");
printf("</html>");

}
```

Comment: Сам apache что вам говорит (логи)?

Comment: `[Sun Aug 26 01:31:37.284813 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 21307:tid 139650995812096] [client 127.0.0.1:54444] End of script output before headers: script.cgi`  Apache error.log

Comment: Ну вот с этой ошибкой уже можно даже на SO поискать вопрос. Пишут, что нужно проверить права на скрипт. Апач его не может прочитать или выполнить

Comment: На это может влиять Apache  неправильные настройки

Comment: Запустите скрипт руками с консоли, передайте ему на стандартный ввод заголовки http запроса и тело запроса. Убедитесь, что он вернул корректные HTTP заголовки ответа (как минимум Content-type) и через два перевода каретки тело ответа. Ошибка Apache гласит, что ваш скрипт не вернул заголовков

Comment: @Mike заголовки через environ, а не stdin доступны¶ Код в вопросе возможно не совпадает с фактическим кодом автора.

Answer (score 0):

Друзья код сработал .Проблемой была неправильная компиляция. Небыло загружено несколько репазиторий  `build-essential`.
Алгоритм действий для правильной работы `CGI`.

Создаем файл `script.c` в папке `gci-bin` (`root@root:/usr/lib/cgi-bin$ sudo touch script.c` ).

Открывем файл  `script.c` (`root@root:/usr/lib/cgi-bin$ sudo nano script.c`).

Добовляем `CGI` скрипты

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void) {
int num;
time_t t;
srand (time ( &t) ) ;

num = rand() % 10;

printf ("Content-type: text/html \n");
printf("Pragma: no-cache\n");
printf ( "\n");
printf("<!DOCTYPE  html>");
printf("<html lang='en'>");
printf("<head>");
printf("<title>Look This Amazing</title>");
printf("<meta charset='utf-8'>");
printf("</head>");
printf("<body>");
printf("<h1>Look This Amazing!</h1>");
printf("</body>");
printf("</html>");

}
```

Сохранаем  `Ctrl+s . Ctrl+x`

Сделаем компиляцию `script.c` на  `gnu` компиляторе

```
 root@root:/usr/lib/cgi-bin$ sudo gcc /usr/lib/cgi-bin/script.c -o script.cgi
```

Комплиляция завершена  `cgi` скрип готов.

Вводим в  `url localhost/cgi-bin/script.cgi`  увидем наш нужный сйат

Кому небудь поможет

Comment: - Что такое "скрипт на языке C" ?! Есть СКРИПТЫ, которые не нуждаются в компиляции и которые сразу можно ложить в *cgi-bin* и есть ИСХОДНЫЕ ПРОГРАММЫ на языке С, которые нужно сначала собрать, а уже потом помещать в папку *cgi-bin*    

- "файл script.c в папке gci-bin" - этот файл может быть где угодно, хоть на другом компе.    

- "Сделаем компиляцию" - только после этого получается     ИСПОЛНИМАЯ программа, которую и нужно разместить в *cgi-bin*.    

- Само название *cgi-bin* говорит о том, что здесь должны лежать БИНАРНЫЕ (т.е. - исполняемые) модули.

Comment: В основном программы работающие по протоколу  `CGI`  верси  1.1  пишутся на языках интерпритаторах. Я  выбрал  язык  `C`    для простоты понемания.Чтоб не добовлять  или включать модули  `Perl` или  `PHP` .Все это для   для простоты понимания.

Comment: *Чтоб не добовлять или включать модули Perl или PHP*

В 99% случаев и то и другое у провайдера уже запущено. Вам не нужно об этом беспокоиться. Модули modPerl и modPhp давно ставятся вместе с апачем по умолчанию.

Comment: В основном  да  это  так .Но я  говорю  про установку с нуля  на локальный кампютер.